# Django Models Task

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a simple to do list whit Django framework. This is the model of Task.

```
class Task(models.Model):

   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   description=models.CharField(max_length=250)
   assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User)
   creation_date =models.DateField(auto_now=True)
   due_date =models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   parent_task=models.ForeignKey(Task)
   list = models.ForeignKey(List)
```

I want to create subtasks. But when I migrate occurred this error:

```
parent_task=models.ForeignKey(Task)
NameError: name 'Task' is not defined
```

Comment: Make sure that you are importing the Task class from wherever you have defined it.

Comment: This is the definition of the Task.

Comment: Ah, understood. Change your line to parent_task=models.ForeignKey('Task'). That should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the same model for subcategorizing, use `self` in `ForeignKey`. For example,

```
class Task(models.Model):

   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   assigned_to = models.ManyToManyField(User)
   creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
   due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   parent_task = models.ForeignKey('self')
   list = models.ForeignKey(List)
```

Comment: why I need to use quotes?

Comment: because that how django expects it

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your model name to `models.ForeignKey()` as a string like below:

```
parent_task = models.ForeignKey('Task')  # Or 'self'
```

Instead of:

```
parent_task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
```